# Read remote file line by line using SCH in java

Tags: java, file-io, sftp

Is there a way to read a remote file line by line using SFTP in java? I have done a little research and as far as i can see, it is possible to read remote file data by bytes using the commons VFS API by Apache.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Apache Camel, it makes it very easy to do so:
https://camel.apache.org/ftp.html